# What lawyer specialization needed to deal with obnoxious neighbors

Tags: criminal-law, lawyer

I am the lucky one that is blessed with 2 obnoxious neighbors on either side of me. They are causing me all sort of issues. From property line wars to out right verbal harassments on a weekly/monthly basis. Calling Cops does nothing to them. I have had it and need to take legal action.

What kind lawyer specialization do I need to deal with these neighbors? This is for US.

Is it?

- criminal law?
- Constitution law?
- civil rights?

Comment: FWIW, in most U.S. states, there are no formally recognized lawyer specializations. Also, not all problems have solutions that lawyers can provide.